# Converting VB.Net MVC to C# MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We have project written in  MVC  Vb.net and I am trying to convert it to  MVC C# .

I am using SharpDevelop for conversion and  was succesfull in converting the class library projects from Vb.net to C#.net but struggling to convert the MVC project from Vb.net to C#.

Sharpdevelop doesn't seem to convert .vbhtml files to .cshtml .

Is there any other method or tool which does this conversion specifically for MVC projects ?

Comment: did u try this http://converter.telerik.com/?

Comment: Confused. Which part is the problem? Are you trying to convert the project or the contents of the files? `struggling to convert the MVC project from Vb.net to C#` or `doesn't seem to convert .vbhtml files to .cshtml` You're not going to magically convert the project from VB.NET to C#. Just won't happen. You can create a new C# MVC project, and just convert each file's contents on a 1x1 basis using the tools listed. For vbhtml files you'll need to create cshtml files and convert whatever VB.NET code is inside your Razor syntax over to C#.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there isn't any other MVC-specific tools. However, the few, available translator tools can cope with MVC.
You can go file-by-file and use one of the following websites:

http://converter.telerik.com/

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/